# Compiling A Mexfile using R CMD SHLIB

Tags: r, matlab, visual-studio, fortran, intel-fortran

I am trying to import a number of Fortran 90 codes into R for a project. They were initially written with a mex (matlab integration of Fortran routines) type compilation in mind. This is what one of the codes look like:

```
# include <fintrf.h>

subroutine mexFunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)

!--------------------------------------------------------------
!                 MEX file for VFI3FCN routine
! 
! log M_{t,t+1} = log \beta + gamma (x_t - x_{t+1})
!     gamma     = gamA + gamB (x_t - xbar)
! 
!--------------------------------------------------------------
implicit none


mwPointer plhs(*), prhs(*)
integer nlhs, nrhs

mwPointer mxGetM, mxGetPr, mxCreateDoubleMatrix
mwPointer nk, nkp, nz, nx, nh
mwSize    col_hxz, col_hz, col_xz

! check for proper number of arguments. 
if(nrhs .ne. 31) then
    call mexErrMsgTxt('31 input variables required.')
elseif(nlhs .ne. 4) then
    call mexErrMsgTxt('4 output variables required.')
endif

! get the size of the input array.
nk  = mxGetM(prhs(5))
nx  = mxGetM(prhs(7))
nz  = mxGetM(prhs(11))
nh  = mxGetM(prhs(14))
nkp = mxGetM(prhs(16))
col_hxz = nx*nz*nh
col_xz  = nx*nz
col_hz  = nz*nh

! create matrix for the return arguments.
plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(nk, col_hxz, 0)
plhs(2) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(nk, col_hxz, 0)
plhs(3) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(nk, col_hxz, 0)
plhs(4) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(nk, col_hxz, 0)

call vfi3fcnIEccB(%val(mxGetPr(plhs(1))), nkp)

return
end

subroutine vfi3fcnIEccB(optK, V, I, div,  &   ! output variables
                        alp1, alp2, alp3, V0, k, nk, x, xbar, nx, Qx, z, nz, Qz, h, nh, kp,                        &
                        alpha, beta, delta, f, gamA, gamB, gP, gN, istar, kmin, kmtrx, ksubm, hmtrx, xmtrx, zmtrx, &
                        nkp, col_hxz, col_xz, col_hz)

use ifwin
implicit none 

! specify input and output variables
integer, intent(in) :: nk, nkp, nx, nz, nh, col_hxz, col_xz, col_hz
real*8, intent(out) :: V(nk, col_hxz), optK(nk, col_hxz), I(nk, col_hxz), div(nk, col_hxz)
real*8, intent(in) :: V0(nk, col_hxz), k(nk), kp(nkp), x(nx), z(nz), Qx(nx, nx), Qz(nz, nz), h(nh)
real*8, intent(in) :: alp1, alp2, alp3, xbar, kmin, alpha, gP, gN, beta, delta, gamA, gamB, f, istar
real*8, intent(in) :: kmtrx(nk, col_hxz), ksubm(nk, col_hz), zmtrx(nk, col_hxz), xmtrx(nk, col_hxz), hmtrx(nk, col_hxz)

! specify intermediate variables
real*8  :: Res(nk, col_hxz), Obj(nk, col_hxz), optKold(nk, col_hxz), Vold(nk, col_hxz), tmpEMV(nkp, col_hz), tmpI(nkp), &
           tmpObj(nkp, col_hz), tmpA(nk, col_hxz), tmpQ(nx*nh, nh), detM(nx), stoM(nx), g(nkp), tmpInd(nh, nz)
real*8  :: Qh(nh, nh, nx), Qxh(nx*nh, nx*nh), Qzxh(col_hxz, col_hxz)
real*8  :: hp, d(nh), errK, errV, T1, lapse
integer :: ix, ih, iter, optJ(col_hz), ik, iz, ind(nh, col_xz), subindex(nx, col_hz)
logical*4 :: statConsole

! construct the transition matrix for kh --- there are nx number of these transition matrix: 3-d
Qh    = 0.0
do ix = 1, nx
    do ih = 1, nh
        ! compute the predicted next period kh
        hp = alp1 + alp2*h(ih) + alp3*(x(ix) - xbar)
        ! construct transition probability vector
        d  = abs(h - hp) + 1D-32
        Qh(:, ih, ix) = (1/d)/sum(1/d)
    end do
end do

! construct the compound transition matrix over (z x h) space
! compound the (x h) space
Qxh   = 0.0
do ix = 1, nx
    call kron(tmpQ, Qx(:, ix), Qh(:, :, ix), nx, 1, nh, nh)
    Qxh(:, (ix - 1)*nh + 1 : ix*nh) = tmpQ
end do
! compound the (z x h) space: h changes the faster, followed by x, and z changes the slowest
call kron(Qzxh, Qz, Qxh, nz, nz, nx*nh, nx*nh)

! available funds for the firm
Res = dexp(xmtrx + zmtrx + hmtrx)*(kmtrx**alpha) + (1 - delta)*kmtrx - f

! initializing 
Obj     = 0.0
optK    = 0.0
optKold = optK + 1.0
Vold    = V0
! Some Intermediate Variables Used in Stochastic Discount Factor
detM    = beta*dexp((gamA - gamB*xbar)*x + gamB*x**2)
stoM    = -(gamA - gamB*xbar + gamB*x)

! Intermediate index vector to facilitate submatrix extracting 
ind = reshape((/1 : col_hxz : 1/), (/nh, col_xz/))
do ix = 1, nx
    tmpInd = ind(:, ix : col_xz : nx)
    do iz = 1, nz
        subindex(ix, (iz - 1)*nh + 1 : iz*nh) = tmpInd(:, iz)
    end do
end do

! start iterations
errK  = 1.0
errV  = 1.0
iter  = 0

T1 = secnds(0.0)

do
if (errV <= 1D-3 .AND. errK <= 1D-8) then
    exit
else
    iter = iter + 1
    do ix = 1, nx
        ! next period value function by linear interpolation: nkp by nz*nh matrix
        call interp1(tmpEMV, k, detM(ix)*(matmul(dexp(stoM(ix)*xmtrx)*Vold, Qzxh(:, subindex(ix, :)))) - ksubm, kp, &
                     nk, nkp, col_hz)
        ! maximize the right-hand size of Bellman equation on EACH grid point of capital stock
        do ik = 1, nk
            ! with istar tmpI is no longer investment but a linear transformation of that
            tmpI   = (kp - (1.0 - delta)*k(ik))/k(ik) - istar
            where (tmpI >= 0.0)
                g  = gP
            elsewhere
                g  = gN
            end where
            tmpObj = tmpEMV - spread((g/2.0)*(tmpI**2)*k(ik), 2, col_hz)
            ! direct discrete maximization
            Obj(ik, subindex(ix, :))  = maxval(tmpObj, 1)
            optJ                      = maxloc(tmpObj, 1)
            optK(ik, subindex(ix, :)) = kp(optJ)
        end do
    end do
    ! update value function and impose limited liability condition
    V = max(Res + Obj, 1D-16)

    ! convergence criterion
    errK  = maxval(abs(optK - optKold))
    errV  = maxval(abs(V - Vold))
    ! revise Initial Guess
    Vold    = V
    optKold = optK

    ! visual
    if (modulo(iter, 50) == 0) then         
        lapse = secnds(T1)          
        statConsole = AllocConsole()
        print "(a, f10.7, a, f10.7, a, f8.1, a)", " errV:", errV, "   errK:", errK, "   Time:", lapse, "s"
    end if
end if
end do

! visual check on errors
lapse = secnds(T1)          
statConsole = AllocConsole()
print "(a, f10.7, a, f10.7, a, f8.1, a)", " errV:", errV, "   errK:", errK, "   Time:", lapse, "s"

! optimal investment and dividend  
I    = optK - (1.0 - delta)*kmtrx
tmpA = I/kmtrx - istar
where (tmpA >= 0)
    div = Res - optK - (gP/2.0)*(tmpA**2)*kmtrx
elsewhere
    div = Res - optK - (gN/2.0)*(tmpA**2)*kmtrx  
end where

return 
end


subroutine interp1(v, x, y, u, m, n, col)
!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Linear interpolation routine similar to interp1 with 'linear' as method parameter in Matlab
! 
! OUTPUT:
!   v - function values on non-grid points (n by col matrix)  
! 
! INPUT: 
!   x   - grid (m by one vector) 
!   y   - function defined on the grid x (m by col matrix)
!   u   - non-grid points on which y(x) is to be interpolated (n by one vector)
!   m   - length of x and y vectors
!   n   - length of u and v vectors
!   col - number of columns of v and y matrices
! 
! Four ways to pass array arguments:
! 1. Use explicit-shape arrays and pass the dimension as an argument(most efficient)
! 2. Use assumed-shape arrays and use interface to call external subroutine
! 3. Use assumed-shape arrays and make subroutine internal by using "contains"
! 4. Use assumed-shape arrays and put interface in a module then use module
!
! This subroutine is equavilent to the following matlab call
! v = interp1(x, y, u, 'linear', 'extrap') with x (m by 1), y (m by col), u (n by 1), and v (n by col)
!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
implicit none

integer :: m, n, col, i, j
real*8, intent(out) :: v(n, col)
real*8, intent(in)  :: x(m), y(m, col), u(n)
real*8    :: prob

do i = 1, n
    if (u(i) < x(1))  then
        ! extrapolation to the left
        v(i, :) = y(1, :) - (y(2, :) - y(1, :))   * ((x(1) - u(i))/(x(2) - x(1)))
    else if (u(i) > x(m)) then
        ! extrapolation to the right
        v(i, :) = y(m, :) + (y(m, :) - y(m-1, :)) * ((u(i) - x(m))/(x(m) - x(m-1)))
    else
        ! interpolation
        ! find the j such that x(j) <= u(i) < x(j+1)
        call bisection(x, u(i), m, j)
        prob    = (u(i) - x(j))/(x(j+1) - x(j))
        v(i, :) = y(j, :)*(1 - prob) + y(j+1, :)*prob
    end if 
end do 

end subroutine interp1


subroutine bisection(list, element, m, k)
!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! find index k in list such that (list(k) <= element < list(k+1)
!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
implicit none

integer*4 :: m, k, first, last, half
real*8    :: list(m), element

first = 1
last  = m
do
    if (first == (last-1)) exit
    half = (first + last)/2
    if ( element < list(half) ) then
        ! discard second half
        last = half
    else
        ! discard first half
        first = half
    end if
end do
  k = first

end subroutine bisection


subroutine kron(K, A, B, rowA, colA, rowB, colB)
!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Perform K = kron(A, B); translated directly from kron.m 
! 
! OUTPUT:
!   K -- rowA*rowB by colA*colB matrix
! 
! INPUT:
!   A -- rowA by colA matrix
!   B -- rowB by colB matrix
!   rowA, colA, rowB, colB -- integers containing shape information
!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
implicit none

integer, intent(in) :: rowA, colA, rowB, colB
real*8, intent(in) :: A(rowA, colA), B(rowB, colB)
real*8, intent(out) :: K(rowA*rowB, colA*colB)

integer :: t1(rowA*rowB), t2(colA*colB), i, ia(rowA*rowB), ja(colA*colB), ib(rowA*rowB), jb(colA*colB)

t1 = (/ (i, i = 0, (rowA*rowB - 1)) /)
ia = int(t1/rowB) + 1
ib = mod(t1, rowB) + 1
t2 = (/ (i, i = 0, (colA*colB - 1)) /)
ja = int(t2/colB) + 1
jb = mod(t2, colB) + 1
K  = A(ia, ja)*B(ib, jb)

end subroutine kron
```

My initial plan was to remove the `mexFunction` subroutine and compile the main Fortran subroutines using the `R CMD SHLIB` command but then I run into the Rtools compiler not knowing where to find the **ifwin** library even though I have the library in my intel fortran compiler folder.

So my first question is:

1) Is there a way for me to tell rtools where to find the ifwin library and any other library I need to include? Or is there a way to include the dependency libraries in the `R CMD SHLIB` command so the compiler can find the necessary libraries and compile?

2) If the answer to two is no, can I some how use the compiled version from Matlab in R. I can compile the file as is in matlab using the `mex Zhang_4.f90` command with no errors.

3) Is there a way of setting up an environment in Visual Studio 2015 so I can compile Fortran subroutines for use in R using the Intel compiler?

When I take out the mexFunction subroutine and try compiling the rest of the code, I get the following error:

```
   D:\SS_Programming\Fortran>R CMD SHLIB Zhang_4.f90
   c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gfortran    -O2  -mtune=core2 -c  Zhang_4.f90 -o 
   Zhang_4.o
   Zhang_4.f90:6.4:
   use ifwin
   1
   Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'ifwin.mod' for reading at (1): No 
   such file or directory
   make: *** [Zhang_4.o] Error 1
   Warning message:
   running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f 
   "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" 
   SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_FCLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_FCLD)' 
   SHLIB="Zhang_4.dll" SHLIB_LIBADD='$(FCLIBS)' WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 
   OBJECTS="Zhang_4.o"' had status 2
```

Comment: That code (`mexFunction`) explicitly calls `mex` symbols. How is that supposed to work in R? Or are you going to delete that part? The Intel compiler should know itself where to look for IFWIN.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vladimir. As I said, I tried compiling the code with the R compiler without the mexFunction subroutine. That failed to work because the R compiler does not know where to find the ifwin library and I have no idea how to point the rtools compiler to the location. I have been searching for solutions online over the past three days with no luck.

Comment: Please post the exact command you tried and the exact error message. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I added the error I am getting. It is basically down to the missing ifwin library.

Comment: But you use `gfortran` in that in that example, not Intel Fortran! You can't use IFWIN in gfortran.

Comment: That is the problem. The rtools compiler is tied to gfortran, it does not allow you to choose compilers. If it had the option of linking to external libraries, I could direct it to the intel fortran library (I dont think it has this option). 
If I can somehow setup the necessary environment within visual studio that allows me to compile fortran dlls ready for use in R, I will not be having this particular compilation error.
But there is no help online as to how to compile a fortran dll within Visual Studio for use in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any other way then rewrite the code to not use IFWIN. Unless you manage to use Intel Fortran for R (that might require recompiling the whole R distribution...). Matlab is tied to Intel Fortran, that's why the code worked there.

You have to adjust the code anyway, you cannot use it as it stands.

Just get rid of the `AllocConsole()` calls and the `print` statements. You will need to use the R routines to print to console. See https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Printing-from-FORTRAN

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback Vladimir. I will rewrite it tomorrow to take out the suggested calls and statements. And post the final code plus adjustments here to help anyone else who may be in a similar situation.